# PRIVACY Card API Authorization

Tags: python-3.x, api

I have recently been working with API's but I am stuck on one thing and it's been holding me back for a few days.
I am trying to work with Privacy's API and I do not understand the Authentication/Authorization process. When I enter the url in a browser I get the error "message": "Please provide API key in Authorization header", even when I use the correct format of Authorization. I also get an error when I make a request in Python. The format I'm using for the url is https://api.privacy.com/v1/card "Authorization: api-key:".
If someone could explain how to work this or simply give an example of how I would make a request through Python3. The API information is in the link below.
Thank you in advance.

https://developer.privacy.com/docs

This is the code I am using in Python. After I run this I receive a 401 status code.

```
import requests
headers={'Authorization': 'api-key:200e6036-6894-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'}
url = 'https://api.privacy.com/v1/card'
r = requests.get(url)
print("Status code:", r.status_code)
```

Comment: You should show some code where you're attempting to call to the API so we know what libraries and such that you are using. Obviously, keep any secret keys or whatnot out of the code you post. This will also tell us what headers you're sending, etc. Are you using the `requests` library?

Comment: I have added my request code. I am very new to this, sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the authentication header to the `get` call. It isn't enough to include it in a header variable. You need to provide those headers to `requests`

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.privacy.com/v1/card', headers={'Authorization': 'api-key 65a9566c-XXXXXXXXXXXX'})

print(response.json())
```